# Can i run php from ssh in jelastic?

Tags: jelastic

when i connect to a nginx node - is there a way to execute php scripts?

I basicly want to run composer, but when calling ./composer.phar it says:

"/usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory"

I suppose i have to run composer locally and upload the files manually, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run PHP via SSH on a Jelastic nginx PHP node.

There's a tutorial at http://kb.layershift.com/jelastic-install-composer describing how to install composer on Apache and nginx PHP nodes on the Jelastic platform. I think it will help with your issue.

**EDIT:** I tested PHP CLI via SSH on a Jelastic nginx PHP node and confirmed it works fine for all PHP versions:

`nginx@nginxphp /var/www $ which php
 /usr/bin/php
nginx@nginxphp /var/www $ echo $PATH
 /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

`nginx@nginxphp /var/www $ php -v
 PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Aug 24 2014 19:41:55) 
 Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
 Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies`

`nginx@nginxphp /var/www $ php -v
 PHP 5.4.32 (cli) (built: Sep  4 2014 10:33:47) 
 Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
 Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies`

`nginx@nginxphp /var/www $ php -v
 PHP 5.5.16 (cli) (built: Sep  4 2014 10:19:16) 
 Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
 Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies`

`nginx@nginxphp /var/www $ php -v
 PHP 5.6.0 (cli) (built: Sep  4 2014 11:18:01) 
 Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
 Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies`

The above is whilst switching the PHP version via the Jelastic dashboard, and is taken using the latest Jelastic version (2.5). If you don't have the same behaviour, I think you should contact your hosting provider for clarification because it should work fine.

Composer install completes ok for me just like this:

`nginx@nginxphp ~ $ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
 #!/usr/bin/env php
 All settings correct for using Composer
 Downloading...`

`Composer successfully installed to: /var/lib/nginx/composer.phar
 Use it: php composer.phar`

Comment: Hello Damien,  

thank you for your answer. I have already read this tutorial. When i log in to a PHP node (with nginx) i get the following result:  

`code
nginx@nginxphp ~ $ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
-bash: php: command not found
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 8030)
`

Is this feature only available with a certain jelastic version?

Comment: I tested the tutorial with a new Apache instance, and its working. Seems that you cant run php scripts on Nginx instances.

Comment: @fabs check my edit. if you don't get the same behaviour please contact your hosting provider's support team for assistance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It seems there has been a bug with my old environment which i created a while ago. After switching the PHP version everything is working as expected and i can now use composer via ssh. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: @fabs that's great to hear! thanks for following up to share your success story.